New Ubuntu Studio install - package updating errors
I hesitated installing Ubuntu on my desktop again after a bad upgrade experience in the past. I gave it another shot yesterday installing Ubuntu Studio on a spare drive. All seemed to go well aside from the known lock screen during installation issue.
Upon updating software via the package manager I immediately receive the following error:
E: The repository 'file:/cdrom noble Release' no longer has a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: file:/cdrom noble Release is not (yet) available (File not found - /cdrom/dists/noble/Release (2: No such file or directory))
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (multiverse/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2
W: Target CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dvd.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources:2

I checked sources and all the typical are checked (main,universe,restriced, and multiverse) and under other software its just noble noble-updates noble-backports showing as checked. Under the updates tab Important security, recommended, and unsupported are checked.

Note the location: file:/cdrom noble. That's what you look for to disable.
